# Математическая подготовка для программирования графики

Tags: разработка-игр, математика, графика

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос адресован тем, кто уже имеет стаж в программировании графики 2D или 3D. Какая математическая подготовка нужна для программирования графики? И насколько часто вам эти знания приходится применять на практике?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Тригонометрия - это азбука, без нее ваще никуда.
2. Вторые азы - это численные методы решения нелинейных уравнений и дифуров 1-го/2-го порядка. Методы Ньютона, Рунге-Кутты, секущих, дихотомии - наше все.
3. Векторная и матричная алгебра: все повороты объектов, камер и проч. делается на матрицах. Кроме того при численном решении различных уравнений постоянно возникает задача обращения матриц (в основном 3-х диагональных). В более извращенном варианте возникает теория кватернионов - грубо говоря арифметика 4-х мерных векторов.
4. Теория сплайнов, понятие ортогональных сплайнов - сглаживание полигонов,поверхностей, линий, огибающих построено них. Кубические сплайны, сплайны Безье, полиномы Чебышева и проч.
5. Для ray tracing'а и пересечения объектов надо уметь находить корни сплайнов. Местами может быть нетривиально
6. При моделировании физики, волн, тумана, дымки и проч. возникает задача решения физических уравнений из классической физики: система диф. уравнений (сохранение момента импульса, инерции, волновое уравнение)

Comment: А насколько это всё реализовано библиотеками? Или приходится каждый раз под определенную задачу писать алгоритмы? Для чего нужны дифуры?

Comment: вы же знактк таблицу умножения, хотя у вас есть калькулятор

Comment: Практически все реализовано уже в виде библиотек/API, кроме численных методов и физики. Да и физика реализуется обычно в виде движка. Дифуры возникают при физике: например моделирование морских волн, вихрей, реалистичных моделей разрушения, падения, столкновения и проч. Но в любом случае, руками надо уметь решать нелинейные уравнения (находить корни), уметь строить аппроксимации/интерполяции/экстраполяции (сплайны).

Comment: То, что вы пытались словесно описать, как теорию интерполяции, называется функциональным анализом.

Comment: Нашел интересные статьи по теме [Линейная алгебра для разработчиков игр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131931/)

Comment: [Статья вредная, с кучей ошибок и просто не правды.](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131931/#comment_4381724)

Comment: Спасибо, если есть ещё какие-то статьи, то запостите их здесь пожалуйста.

Comment: @Spectre ну насчет неправды не соглашусь. Просто статья изложена очень на простом уровне - что в общем то характерно для западной мат.школы. На уровне 1-го семестра ВУЗа

Comment: да я в матане полный профан, просто убедительный коммент попался

Comment: Оффтоп. Недавно читал книгу на английском про тригонометрию и просто поразился насколько просто все излагается. У наших такого пока нету, но зато есть мой любимый автор "Киркинский" по которому я линейку и аналитическую геометрию самостоятельно изучал. Планирую матан в будущем также, а то в универе балду гонял когда он был, а теперь интересно стало.

Comment: >То, что вы пытались словесно описать, как теорию интерполяции, 
>называется функциональным анализом.
Я нигде не писал про теорию интерполяции, а функанализ гораздо более шире чем интерполяция :)

Comment: @Barmaley, писали-писали ;-) Там, где много букв, интерполяция делается свёрткой исходной табличной функции со специально подобранным ядром, среди которых предложенные Чебышевым, Безье, Ланцошем итд. Так что для передискретизации изображений как минимум нужны основы ФА.

Comment: кажется кто-то [форумом](http://math.hashcode.ru/) ошибся=)